# Using a node editing form on a page that not a node edit page

Tags: 7, routes

I have created a menu item, as reported below. I have taken the form ID from the page source (form id=listorious-list-power-100-node-form) but when I go to the specified URL, I get the following error:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'node_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 771 of /var/www/drm6/drm001/site/includes/form.inc).

The form is the standard node form found on node/add/listorious-list-power-100.

```
$items['admin/config/listorious/settings/add'] = array(
  'title' => 'add Listorious List item',
  'description' => 'Add list item information.',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('listorious_list_power_100_node_form'),
  'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
      'file path' => drupal_get_path('module','node'),
      'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
```

needs to be added to the array.