# How can I have multiple versions of the same form, in different pages?

Tags: forms

There is a default Drupal 7 form called "user_profile_form". I would like to show certain elements of this form on one page of my website, and then a different set of elements from this same form on another page.

Is there a way to either:

a) have multiple versions of the same form (keeping the same ID) or
b) clone the form and then modify it (there will be two different form IDs)

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `hook_menu()` with `drupal_get_form()` to use any form on any path (see [Using a node editing form on a page that not a node edit page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/reusing-an-existing-form/3756#3756)).

You can then use `hook_form_alter()`, and get that to work differently depending on the path.

You can use `$_GET['q']` for the full path or `arg()` to get parts of the path. and use `if()` logic to determine how to alter the form.

Comment: Thank for your answer Jeremy. The form that will be generated depends on the path arguments, so then I can use if() statements within my hook_form_alter() to screen the path that is being called.  Am I reading you correctly?  If so, then I have to bother you with one more question: from within the hook_form_alter() how can I determine the path arguments of the menu callback?

Comment: $_GET['q'] contains the full path, arg() allows to access each part separately.